# SSRS Format Date Long Date without Zeros

Tags: date, reporting-services, format, ssrs-2008

we have an element on the report that appears as such

`Print Values by: Thursday, July 01, 2021`

The code we have it appears in our SSRS file as such

`="Print Values by: " & FormatDateTime(Parameters!printBy_deadline.Value, DateFormat.LongDate)`

We can't separate it out from the string. The users want it to appear exactly the same

`Print Values by: Thursday, July 1, 2021` without the zero but the rest should remain the same. I've reviewed the other formats but they don't appear to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FORMAT function to do custom formatting of dates and numbers rather than using the limited number of formats with FormatDateTime.

```
="Print Values by: " & FORMAT(Parameters!printBy_deadline.Value, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")
```

The result for TODAY is:

> Friday, April 30, 2021

The d is for day. When there's 2 **d**'s, the day of the month will always have a leading 0. If it's one **d**, it will have one or two digits. Three **d**'s will show the day as the day name abbreviated while 4 **d**'s will show the full day name.

The name logic is similar for **M** for the months.